# Getting the complete URL instead of only the path using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python

I'm just starting to learn Python and I'm trying to write a script using BeautifulSoup. Here's what I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from six.moves import urllib
import ssl

sitelist = [
'https://www.google.com/search?q=%s',
'https://www.bing.com/search?q=%s',
'http://www.ask.com/web?q=%s',
'https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%s'
]

ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

query = raw_input("What do you want to search for? ")

for url in sitelist:
    url = url % (query)
    try:
        result = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(result, "lxml")

        for link in soup.find_all('a'):
            link = link.get('href')
            try:
                if query in link:
                    print(link)
            except:
                pass
    except:
        pass
```

So when I run this script, if I do a search for "stackoverflow" I get results like this:

```
/images/search?q=stackoverflow&FORM=HDRSC2
/videos/search?q=stackoverflow&FORM=HDRSC3
/maps?q=stackoverflow&mkt=en&FORM=HDRSC4
https://stackoverflow.com/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/
```

And then further down the list some of these same results will occur again. I understand why that happens. The same search with multiple search engines will yield duplicate results. What I don't understand are the mixed results. Some of these are complete urls. But then other results contain only the path e.g.

```
/images/search?q=stackoverflow&FORM=HDRSC2
/videos/search?q=stackoverflow&FORM=HDRSC3
/maps?q=stackoverflow&mkt=en&FORM=HDRSC4
```

So my question is 2 parts:

1. How can I strip the duplicates from the results?
2. How can I return the complete URL instead of just the path?

The second question is the one I'm most interested in. If need be, I can filter out the duplicates later in Bash.

Also, any and all constructive criticism of this script is welcome. :)

Comment: (1) Convert the list of the results into a set. (2) Use `urllib.request.urljoin()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's literally returning you the content of the links it finds on the page.

The ones beginning with `http` are the links pointing to the site it has found. The other ones are internal links, relative to the search page itself - in this case, they are pointing at other search options that the search engine offers.

If you want to make these absolute URLs, you will need to join them with the original URL you sent:

```
from urllib.request import urljoin

...

if not link.startswith('http'):
    link = urljoin(url, link)
```